# Is there a way to remove unused lines of a JS Library?

Tags: javascript

I currently coded something awesome based on a JS Library, and I want to remove every useless line that is doing nothing but take more time to download from the server.

**What is the best way to keep track of what piece of code was used/unused when my code executed?** (So I can remove the unused code)

My first thoughts are to put `"var log += "<br />Function name was used."` on every function and remove every function that wasn't called. But I am curious about if there is another way

*I want to point out that modifying certain JS Libraries might violate their Licences and possibly cause strong legal issues. So if anyone is reading this and is planning to do the same thing as me, please read carefully the Licence(s) before you even attempt to do this!*

Comment: Maybe look into a solution which uses code coverage data? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249/are-there-any-good-javascript-code-coverage-tools

Comment: @bobbymcr using a JS code coverage is a great solution, you should post this as an answer before someone else does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my estimation, the best way to keep track of which code has actually executed would be to use a code coverage measurement tool.  There are several available for Javascript, many of which are outlined in a previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249/are-there-any-good-javascript-code-coverage-tools .

Of course, this only tracks the code that has executed as a result of the test suite you are running it against, and would not be a foolproof way to find "completely dead" (i.e. unreachable) code. But it's a start...